# appending JSON data?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I want to append my JSON data for sending to server..

I have this code

```
var json = JSONSerializer.toJson(data2)
```

and this is my data2

```
var data2 = Activitiesdata (type: leftlabel.text!, amount: qtytext.text.toInt()!)
```

and this is my Activitiesdata

```
class Activitiesdata
{
    var type = "type"
    var amount = 0
    init (type: String, amount: Int)
    {
        self.type = type
        self.amount = amount
    }
}
```

when I click on a icon (lets say softball) and I println the outcome like this

```
{"type": "Softball", "amount": 90}
```

but whenever I click another icon, the outcome like this

```
{"type": "Badminton", "amount": 60}
```

how to append the data? so that the outcome like this whenever I click the second button and so on..

```
{"type": "Softball", "amount": 90} {"type": "Badminton", "amount": 60}
```

or is it possible to make like this

```
{"type": "Softball", "amount": 90, "type": "Badminton", "amount": 60} // (only 1 bracket)
```

thanks

using array is a good idea, but I always get compile error .. please help thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but when working in JSON i love this http://www.bodurov.com/JsonFormatter/

Answer (score 0):

You put not enough information to answer, but it looks like you create json object every time you press the button, that's why the old value in a variable `var json` is replaced by a new one. You must first create an array of the objects and then serialize it into json.
Your JSON result will looks somthing like this:

```
{[{"type": "Softball", "amount": 90}, {"type": "Badminton", "amount": 60}]}
```

I do not know what mechanism you use to serializing, but if it write in the style in which it is written in your code, it will be something like this:

```
var dataArray: [Activitiesdata] = []
// click on a icon
let firstElement = Activitiesdata (type: leftlabel.text!, amount: qtytext.text.toInt()!)
dataArray.append(firstElement)
// click another icon
let secondElement = Activitiesdata (type: otherlabel.text!, amount: otherText.text.toInt()!)
dataArray.append(secondElement)
// serialize array to json in your style
var json = JSONSerializer.toJson(dataArray)
```

There is a good library for working with JSON - https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON